# Computer reboots every hour or so. Which logs could give me insight as to why this happens

Tags: overheating

new to Linux. I have had the same issue on Windows 7, then the problem subsided after I installed Ubuntu, but it has started back again, it reboots about every hour or so.

I have read that this may due tu over heating, so I opened up the machine to notice that the chassis fan's bearing is seased, so that might be why it is happening.

In any case, I would like to know if there are any specific logs I should look at to get insight as to why this happening.

I did install a program called sensors, which gives me some information:

```
   $ sensors
   nouveau-pci-0100
   Adapter: PCI adapter
   GPU core:     +1.32 V  (min =  +1.20 V, max =  +1.32 V)
   fan1:           0 RPM
   temp1:        +59.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                   (crit = +125.0°C, hyst =  +2.0°C)
                   (emerg = +130.0°C, hyst = +10.0°C)
   coretemp-isa-0000
   Adapter: ISA adapter
   Core 0:       +38.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
   Core 1:       +37.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

But it does not look like it is overheating. In any case I have ordered an $8 fan on Amazon. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many mbs/cpu's shutdown at 100oC; your 95oC (gpu) is extremely hot. It could be your gpu can't shutdown your system, and it reboots

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. If the computer reboots because of the GPU temperature, would there be a mention in a log somewhere and if so, which one?

Comment: Nope - if hardware reboots; the OS doesn't have a clue. The signal (electrically) goes to the PSU and reboot/off state changes.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. Maybe the replacement fan will be helpful.